# Is I should duplicate fields in two related models

Tags: django, django-models

I have two related models. First model Fixture with following fields

```
class Fixture(models.Model):
     fixture_id = models.IntegerField()
     team_id = models.ForeignKey("Team")
     team_logo = models.ForeignKey("Team")
```

and second model Team with following fields

```
class Team(models.Model):
     team_id = models.IntegerField()
     team_logo = models.URLField()
```

In above code some fields in fixture model like team_id and team_logo are duplicate team_id and team_logo fields in Team model. If team_id in fixture model need me to establish relation with team model but team_logo is doing nothing only duplicate.
Here is my question accordind the first database normalization rule "each record should be unique" is it right way to store in fixture model team_logo?

Answer (score 0):

In Django, every model by default will have an integer based `id` field (you can reference it by `pk`). Also, given your data and the fact that you're using
a relational database, you don't need to duplicate data from one model to the other. For example, this is sufficient:

```
class Fixture(models.Model):
     team = models.ForeignKey("Team")
     description = models.TextField()


class Team(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     logo = models.URLField()
```

This lets you do:

```
# assume this is some uploaded file:
logo_image_file = ...

team_lfc = Team.objects.create(name='Liverpool FC', logo=logo_image_file)
fixture1 = Fixture.objects.create(team=team_lfc, description='Manchester City in August')

# access the 'auto' id/pk:

# these two are the same
fixture1.pk
fixture1.id

# these two are the same
team_lfc.pk
team_lfc.id

# access foreign key object:
fixture1.team

# access foreign key id:
fixture1.team_id
fixture1.team.id
fixture1.team.pk

# access the team's logo from a fixture instance:
fixture1.team.logo
```